# I want to loop through array elements (array of string)

Tags: c#, arrays, strip

I am trying to loop array in C# and then with that elements I am trying to loop the value based on space but it is not working.

```
public void Find()
{
    string[] stores = {"Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401","Hi there should"};

    foreach(var store in stores)
    {
        foreach (var stor in store)
        {
            string result = string.Join("", stor);
            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is as following:

> Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401 
>   Hi there should

My expected Output is:

> Third 
>   Street 
>   Promenade 
>   1220 
>   3rd 
>   St 
>   Santa 
>   Monica 
>   CA 
>   90401 
>   Hi 
>   There 
>   Should

I want the result be as above format (My expected Output) in C#.

Comment: The output occurs on the Console.Write. Put a breakpoint there and see what the debugger tells you.

Comment: What exactly would you like to do? Do you like to get all words in `stores` array?

Comment: Use Console.WriteLine instead of Console.Write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Split` function.

```
string[] stores = { "Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401", "Hi there should" };

foreach (string store in stores)
{
    var result = store.Split(' ').Select(w => w.Trim(','));

    foreach (string word in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `foreach (string word in result )` ?

Comment: You get output with `,` for : `Promenade,` `,Santa` `Monica,` ?

Comment: Why are you using `ToList()`? It is costly and you absolutely dont need it here. Also, you shouldnt use `Trim()`. What if the user use another separator?

Answer (score 1):

First remove all unwanted characters, then Split by space.

[Working Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Isn13j) on .NETFiddle

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public static void Main()
{
    string[] stores = {"Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401","Hi there should"};

    Func<string, string> clean = x => new String(x.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == ' ').ToArray());

    var outputs = stores.SelectMany(store => clean(store).Split(' '));

    foreach (var output in outputs)
        Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

I edited with a full Linq answer.

By the way, you shouldnt split addresses by hand. You may want to use a lib or a service for this and then play only with coordinates. Addresses are a mess. Dont reliable on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
string[] stores = { "Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401", "Hi there should" };
string[] lstSplittedStores = string.Join(" ,", stores).Split(new[] { " ", " ," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (var item in lstSplittedStores)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem is in line : `foreach (var stor in store) { .. }` where you seem to expect division of `store` string to words while in practice it is division to single characters. This is what a string is - a series of characters.

So the scope in 2 foreach actually has always just 1 character and no "joining" ever happens.

To get words from string, use `String.Split()` instead. Read more about [String.Split from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
string[] stores = { "Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St ,Santa Monica, CA 90401", "Hi there should" };
char[] separators = new char[] { ' ', ',' };
foreach (String store in stores)
{
    String[] storeWords = store.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (String word in storeWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
}
```

If you ever feel unsure about what's going with types then change the `var` keywords to explicit types. This way compiler will show where your intention differs from written syntax.